# Do I need to use newValue as parameter to pass it to function when I use observable in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

allList is private variable, Code A works well.

I hope to write a fun for Code A, which one is correct between Code B and Code C ?

If both Code B and Code C are correct, which one is more better between Code B and Code C ?

**Code A**

```
private var allList by Delegates.observable(listOf<MSetting>())
    { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        btnRestore.isEnabled = newValue.size >= 1
    }
```

**Code B**

```
private var allList by Delegates.observable(listOf<MSetting>())
    { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        setButtonsByRecord()
    }

    private fun setButtonsByRecord(){
        btnRestore.isEnabled=allList.size>=1
    }
```

**Code C**

```
private var allList by Delegates.observable(listOf<MSetting>())
    { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        setButtonsByRecord(newValue)
    }



    private fun setButtonsByRecord(my:List<MSetting>){
        btnRestore.isEnabled=my.size>=1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Code B (because ["The value of the property has already been changed when this callback is invoked"](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html)) and Code C would be correct, but I'd only do it if you need to use this function somewhere else too. And in this case choice between B and C would depend on which of the functions you have a use for.